# Call js function with onclick in twig and symfony

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I made a moderate post function, but I'm not sure that my method is secure.

Here is the controller

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @Route ("/forum/moderate/post", name="post_moderate")
 * @return Response
 */

public function moderateAction(Request $request, PostRepository $postRepository)
{
    $reason = htmlentities($request->request->get('reason'));
    $postId = (int)htmlentities($request->request->get('postId'));

    if (empty($reason)) {
        return new Response(json_encode('fail'), 500);
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $post = $postRepository->findOneBy(array('id' => $postId));
    $post->setModerateReason($reason);
    $em->persist($post);

    $em->flush();

    return new Response(json_encode('ok'), 200);
}
```

For the moment there is not security controls.

My link in twig have somes attributes:
An id, because every post must have his own moderate button,
A data href, to get the path in the js file. 
There is also a moderateLink class for the click event.

```
 <a class="btn btn-danger btn-squared btn-sm mr-2 text-white moderateLink"
 title="Modérer le commentaire" id="moderateLink-{{ post.id }}" 
 data-href=" {{ path('post_moderate') }}"><i class="fas fa-gavel"></i></a>
```

Here is my post.js file:

```
$(function () {


    $('.moderateLink').on('click', moderate);

});

function moderate () {

    let id = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id.split('-');
    id = id[1];

    var reason = prompt('Entrez la raison: ');
    var url = $(this).attr('data-href')

    if (reason != null && reason.trim() != '') {

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            crossDomain: false,
            data: 'reason=' + reason + '&postId=' + id,
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function (res) {
                if (res == 'ok') {
                //
                }
            }
        });
    } else if (reason != null) {
        alert('Vous devez entrer une raison.');
        return;
    }
}
```

The big problem is than any user can edit the HTML file to put the needed attributes and class name. I don't want they access to the popup box.

**I tried something like that:**

Twig:

```
 <a class="btn btn-danger btn-squared btn-sm mr-2 text-white"
 title="Modérer le commentaire"
 onclick="moderate({{post.id}})"><i class="fas fa-gavel"></i></a>
```

Post.js with FOSjsRoutingBundle ( https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/index.html ):

```
const routes = require('../../public/js/fos_js_routes.json');
import Routing from '../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting- 
bundle/Resources/public/js/router.min.js';


$(function () {

    moderate = function(id){
        Routing.setRoutingData(routes);
        var reason = prompt('Entrez la raison: ');
        var url = Routing.generate('post_moderate');

        if (reason != null && reason.trim() != '') {

            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                crossDomain: false,
                data: 'reason=' + reason + '&postId=' + id,
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                success: function (res) {
                    if (res == 'ok') {
                        //
                    }
                }
            });
        } else if (reason != null) {
            alert('Vous devez entrer une raison.');
            return;
        }
```

But in this case, the console tell me that moderate is not define. 
If I remove the import at top, the function works but I can't pass the path to js.

I do not know how to reach my goal, I would like to use my second method, but I don't know how ...

Comment: I'm guessing it is because `moderate` lives inside the `jquery` scope at this point. Move it outside `$(function() {  ... })`

Comment: If I move it from $(function(){}, it tell me the same

Comment: Hello, maybe send a JsonResponse::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST instead of a 500 if reason is not posted or if $post is null forthe postId you receive doesn't exist in database

Comment: If it gets to the page/HTML then they can mess with it - and you need to protect against that server side.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer truly on the security part but more how to call the ajax and an `onclick`/`click` event handler.

Just get that event handler outside of the HTML and into code.
Here I wrapped all the links just for clarity.  I used a data attribute to hold the id instead i.e.:

Sample: only here to show the data attribute:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-squared btn-sm mr-2 text-white" title="Modérer le commentaire" data-postid="{{post.id}}"><i class="fas fa-gavel"></i></a>
```

**Now this has really little to do with the security - you need to do that server side - consider ALL HTML to not be secure.**

This does not really run here but perhaps can get you further along:

```js
const routes = require('../../public/js/fos_js_routes.json');
import Routing from '../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.min.js';

$(function() {
  $('.link-container').on('click','.link-thing', function(event) {
      const id = $(this).data("postid");
      Routing.setRoutingData(routes);
      let reason = prompt('Entrez la raison: ');
      let url = Routing.generate('post_moderate');
      let data = 'reason=' + reason + '&postId=' + id;
      if (reason != null && reason.trim() != '') {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: data,
          dataType: 'JSON'
          // async: false // not async:false, this is deprected and a bad idea
        }).done(function(res) {
            if (res == 'ok') {
              //
            }
        });
    } else if (reason != null) {
      alert('Vous devez entrer une raison.');
      return;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.link-container {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: solid 1px #ddddff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="fun-container">
  <div class="link-container">
    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-squared btn-sm mr-2 text-white link-thing" title="Modérer le commentaire" data-postid="12345"><i class="fas fa-gavel"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="link-container">
    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-squared btn-sm mr-2 text-white link-thing" title="Modérer le commentaire" data-postid="454545"><i class="fas fa-gavel"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="link-container">
    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-squared btn-sm mr-2 text-white link-thing" title="Modérer le commentaire" data-postid="7532"><i class="fas fa-gavel"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="link-container">
    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-squared btn-sm mr-2 text-white link-thing" title="Modérer le commentaire" data-postid="8765412"><i class="fas fa-gavel"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```